# How to disable Alt-f shortcut binding from file menu access key under Cinnamon Mint 13 (Maya)?

Tags: bash, terminal, linux-mint, shortcuts

I'm running Cinnamon on Linux Mint 13 (Maya).  I want to disable the terminal file menu access shortcut as it's bound to Alt+f and I'd rather use that shortcut to move forward a word in bash.

I looked at "[How do I disable the keyboard shortcut for menu in Linux Mint 13?](https://superuser.com/questions/433724/how-do-i-disable-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-menu-in-linux-mint-13)", and while I found the shortcut binding for "Active the window menu" (under Menu -> Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts), I couldn't find a configuration for file menu access in any of the places suggested.

Answer (score 12):

What DID work for me, was this (care of the Ubuntu forum, "[SOLVED bash keyboard shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/433724/how-do-i-disable-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-menu-in-linux-mint-13)"):

> In gnome-terminal, go to Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts and check "Disable
>   all menu access keys (such as Alt+f to open File Menu)".

It carries over between terminal sessions, and the general menu shortcut key (default F10) is still enabled and will get you straight into the file menu.

Answer (score 4):

No, solution is another. If you use MATE Terminal you need go to Edit->Keyboard shortcuts and uncheck option "Enable the menu shortcut key (F10 by default)" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you use Mate Terminal, you can uncheck "Enable menu access keys (such as Alt+F to open the File menu)" in Edit > Keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Mint 21.2 XFCE, It can be solved by going to the following option of the Terminal:

`Edit > Preferences > Advanced` Here under `Shortcuts` section, tick mark the option `Disable all menu access keys (such as Alt+f)`