# Inkscape dialog too large to fit in the screen

Tags: ubuntu, inkscape, layout, dialog

I cannot fully access the "document properties" of inkscape.  See the bottom part of the screenshot. The last few options are not visible, and I am not able to scroll down either.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Cinnamon desktop environment. Inkscape version: 0.92

[image: Document Properties dialog]

Answer (score 2):

A work around is to dock it to the right side of the window thus making it scrollable, now enabling you to access the bottom options.

To dock it:

1. Click and hold the "Document Properties" area, notice the location of the pointer.

[image: 1: Click and hold the "Document Properties"]

2. Drag to the right and release.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The new Document Properties in Inkscape 0.92 dialog is indeed about 700 pixels high, which may be large for some screen resolutions. It is not resizeable below this size. What your screenshot shows is that the bottom of the dialog is out of your screen.

First to reassure you, you're not missing much, there is nothing below "Use antialiasing" checkbox.

Then, I am not sure it can be considered as a bug, since an application can expect that you have some minimum screen resolution. Thus, if this cannot be improved, you can find work arounds: your display environment (presumably gnome) may be set in "auto-hiding" mode or along vertical sides of the screen, giving you the extra few pixels you need in height. Alternatively, you can use window decorations that are narrower. Finally, you can move the window up farther than the top screen border, so as to access the options lower down, by using the window decoration menu (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> if there is no button), then select `Move`.

Comment: The shortcut that you've mentioned doesn't seem to work. The dialog doesn't go up. It is only moving down. 
PS: My desktop environment is cinnamon.

Comment: @kJd47: I'm not using cinnamon, sorry. According to this post, http://superuser.com/questions/433724/how-do-i-disable-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-menu-in-linux-mint-13/456021#456021, it can be configured to...

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity in my comment, what I meant is, the shortcut is working, but the move function doesn't seem to work as you said. I cannot move the window above the upper edge of the screen.

Comment: well, this might be a peculiarity of your DE. Did you try using keyboard arrows one you've used the shortcut and clicked "move"? What about the other suggestions for making room on top/bottom?